# Populate picklist options with remote data?

Tags: remote-access

I have a custom picklist field in the opportunities object that is on a standard simple page layout with nothing complex going on. The only complex point is that my custom picklist should ideally have its contents coming from a remote data source on another website.   The aim is simply to avoid maintenance in two places and have the picklist in Salesforce update from the other source.

What technology needs applying at the source end I don't mind, I'm open to anything.

Yet I'm not sure what is the simplist way of achieving this from Salesforce.      Would I need to schedule the request as well or would it be run each time the page layout and picklist is rendered?

Comment: Do you want to store the picklist values fetched from external site into Salesforce field? If yes, how frequent do you need the update in picklist field to happen?

Comment: Hi @SanTosh  the values could be stored or just read in each time the page loads.   If stored they wouln't need refreshing that often, just once a day, maybe even less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/) allows picklist values (the values presented in the select list in the UI) to be added. This [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_picklist.htm) suggests de-activated is possible which may effectively mean delete is supported, but you would need to test or Google further to be sure. You can invoke this API from outside Salesforce using SOAP or REST calls or thanks to this [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) from within Salesforce.

You would schedule say a daily (or hourly) update; the work would take much too long to do each time the page is displayed and in any case it is awkward to run code each time layout-based UI is displayed. Depending on where the updating code runs, you would need to authenticate with one or both sides.

Enough complexity is involved that this would only be worth doing if the changes were frequent or if it was critical that the two systems remained in sync.